# Not getting new voice mail after switched iphones/sim card

Tags: iphone

I switched iphones from a 5c to a 5s - both on AT&T. Got a new SIM card from AT&T store.  The Contacts and **old** voicemails are all there and I can dial out as well as receive calls.

However **new** voicemails are nowhere to be seen.  How can this be corrected?  The phone is on ios 10.2 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ring your provider - sounds like something needs to be switched over from their end.
[I've had similar happen with an updated SIM, same phone, same number.]

Comment: Yes AT&T needed to update the imieo (or something like that)